# DataGrid bound to BindingList (or ObservableCollection) does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have tried so many solutions on SO but none works for me. The DataGrid is never updated.

I have one class (UserTab) inherited from UserControl with a XAML and one class with the data (TableController).

**XAML (UserTab):**

```
<local:BaseTab.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <controller:TableController x:Key="tablecontroller" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</local:BaseTab.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredEntries, Source={StaticResource tablecontroller}}"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}"
                                    Header="{StaticResource id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}"
                                    Header="{StaticResource name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding desc}"
                                    Header="{StaticResource desc}" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have also tried this with changing `Mode` or `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

**TableController**

```
public class TableController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList<entry> _allEntries;
    private BindingList<entry> _filteredEntries = new BindingList<entry>();

    public IList<entry> AllEntries
    {
        get
        {
            return _allEntries;
        }
        set
        {
            _allEntries = value;
        }
    }
    public BindingList<entry> FilteredEntries
    {
        get
        {
            return _filteredEntries;
        }
        set
        {
            _filteredEntries = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredEntries");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new InventarDBEntities())
        {
            AllEntries = dbContext.entry.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
            //FilteredEntries = new BindingList<entry>(AllEntries);
        }
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        foreach (entry entry in AllEntries)
        {
            FilteredEntries.Add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

The `FilteredEntries` later only contains a sublist of AllEntries. I used this code to test the binding. First `FilteredEntries` is empty and the DataGrid is empty too. When clicking a button and `TestMethod` is fired  `FilteredEntries` contains entries, but the DataGrid is still empty. I've also tried `ObservableCollection` and creating a property in `UserTab.xaml.cs` just forwarding the `FilteredEntries` from `TableController`. Nothing worked.

**Update:**
Seems like the first Binding does not work because when I set ItemSource via code it updates when changing the List.

Comment: Just a hint: you don't need two lists when using ICollectionView and the inbuild filter logic. You can have one list will all entries and you view will only display the filtered ones.

Comment: FilteredEntries should be an ObservableCollection and not a BindingList. And you should call the NotifyPropertyChanged method in the setter of the AllEntries property.

Comment: But ICollectionView has not some of the nice methods/properties. And is it possible to bind a ICollectionView to a dataGrid?

Comment: ICollectionView? I am talking about the ObservableCollection<T> type. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the `FilteredEntries` property to `ObservableCollection<entry>` and call the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method in the setter of the `AllEntries` property:

```
public class TableController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList<entry> _allEntries;
    private ObservableCollection<entry> _filteredEntries = new ObservableCollection<entry>();

    public IList<entry> AllEntries
    {
        get
        {
            return _allEntries;
        }
        set
        {
            _allEntries = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AllEntries");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<entry> FilteredEntries
    {
        get
        {
            return _filteredEntries;
        }
        set
        {
            _filteredEntries = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredEntries");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new InventarDBEntities())
        {
            AllEntries = dbContext.entry.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
            //FilteredEntries = new BindingList<entry>(AllEntries);
        }
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        foreach (entry entry in AllEntries)
        {
            FilteredEntries.Add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

> That does not work. It has to be something with be binding not the updating. When I set the dataGrid's dataContext to TableController.FilteredEntries it works and all updates are displayed

Of course you must set the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` or any of its parent elements to an instance of the `TableController` class for you to be able to bind to it.

I don't know why you are trying to bind to a resource. You shouldn't add the `TableController` as a resource but set it as the `DataContext` of the element:

```
<local:BaseTab.DataContext>
    <controller:TableController />
</local:BaseTab.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredEntries}"
      SelectionUnit="Cell"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
```

Or:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredEntries}"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.DataContext>
        <controller:TableController />
    </DataGrid.DataContext>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That does not work. It has to be something with be binding not the updating. When I set the dataGrid's dataContext to TableController.FilteredEntries it works and all updates are displayed.

Comment: Of course you need to set the DataContext to an instance of a TableController and set the properties of this specific instance. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes it works that way, thanks. But I can't set the DataContext for the whole UserControl.

Comment: Why not? Set the DataContext of the DataGrid then.

Comment: Thank you! Works like expected.